# Extracting text from pdf data stream in php

Tags: php, pdf, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [extracting content from pdf using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783066/extracting-content-from-pdf-using-php)

I have a url which returns a page with some pdf data along with html...I removed the HTML part and now the data string contains data in pdf format.I need to extract text content of the pdf file from this string.Is there a way to do that in php?I have googled and found no working way to do that..The data starts with %PDF and ends in EOF .B/w that there is some unrecognizable characters(possibly binary data)

Comment: The site tem might want to look at this http://bejeweled.popcap.com/html5/0.9.12.9490/html5/Bejeweled.html to put PDF in HTML

Answer (score 0):

You may use [pdftotext](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/converter-pdf-files-to-text-format-command/) application to get the contents of the pdf.